# What does (the justification of) metaphilosophical pluralism consist in?

Tags: metaphilosophy, value-pluralism

[Logical pluralism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-pluralism/) means some sort of openness to, or even going between, multiple theories/systems of logic. Like a fluid logical eclecticism, perhaps (I am not tracking the inclusivism/pluralism distinction well right now!). [Religious pluralism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/religious-pluralism/) is similar, with an emphasis less on (but not to the exclusion of!) possible eclectic moves and more on individual/cultural "integrity."

Now metaphilosophically, we have approaches and styles such as *ordinary-language*, *Wittgensteinian-therapeutic*, *Kantian-transcendental*, *Quinean naturalized-epistemology*, *old-school scholastic* or *Socratic*, *quasi-Buddhist*, *other historically syncretistic*, etc. (some of these come across as first-order philosophy more than meta-theories *over* that first order, I suppose). **So is a *metaphilosophical* pluralist someone who thinks that each of these has its own place, either relative to specific problems of philosophy or to the interests/preferences of these-or-those philosophers?** I find myself going back and forth on ordinary-language analysis, for example; sometimes I sympathize with, and even practice, this style of philosophy, other times it seems frivolously uninformative (on a philosophical, if not a linguistic, level). This alongside a vivid (but not absolute) commitment to formalism or at least rigorousness, as well as a longstanding fascination with Kantian reasoning in both metaphysics and metaethics, etc. **Is metaphilosophical pluralism motivated by the same kinds of structural considerations as logical or religious pluralism, so that anyone favoring those "ought" to favor this kind of metaphilosophy as well?**

**Note:** much of the SEP seems to proceed by way of a kind of *methodological* metaphilosophical pluralism, where the authors of various articles frame debates using a wide range of citations, usually leaving off debates *post media res* and so with an invitation, explicit or implicit, for the audience to reflect and research more of their (the audience's) own accord. It is rare to find, as in the article on Quine's set theory, one of the Aquinas articles, or the creationism-vs.-evolution article, more strident or at least insistent tones of voice. **Is methodological metaphilosophical pluralism, then, an image of metaphilosophical pluralism as a kind of standpoint, or rather are both the same thing, here, with the same justification or justifying force to their names?**

---

**EDIT: a random citation**

Orellana, et. al.[[98](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337189681_Metaphilosophical_Pluralism_and_Paraconsistency_From_Orientative_to_Multi-level_Pluralism)] seems relevant, and surprisingly dated (not necessarily *out*dated, to be fair!).

Comment: The big difference is that not each philosopher's field of interest covers every philosophical problems... In science sometimes there are competing research programs: it is hard to imagine someone being pluralist: e.g. someone supporting both the Copenhagen interpretation of QM and the b"hidden variables" one.

Comment: Logical pluralist is different: from Boole and Frege to Hilbert etc, the philosophical view of logic moved from the "logic" of human thought to the "logic" of mathematics. Modern logic deals with a wider field: modal, time, epistemic, doxastic, etc and we can imagine that different "applications" of human reason and language may need different formal system to be regimented.

Comment: Re philosophy, if philosophers are "competitors" e.g. on the metaphysical plan, it is hard to imagine someone being both idealist and materialist. At the same time, not every philosophical theory cover all range of problems: what about Wittgenstein and war? and Quine about art?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I should differentiate 2nd- from 3rd-order/level philosophy, then, and so on. Idealism vs. materialism might be on level 2, while Wittgensteinian-therapy vs. scholasticism vs. experimental philosophy might be on level 3, etc. It would be a strange ordeal of thought to keep going and going, trying to find a "most" encompassing domain of strategies. ω-metaphilosophy sounds poetic but perhaps impossible to work with, and yet hardly scratches the surface of transfinite iterations of *x*-metaphilosophy...

Comment: It's not clear from your question: are you coining a new term "philosophical pluralism" in analogy to "logical pluralism" or are you referring to an existing term "philosophical pluralism" which  has been previously defined and discussed? A quick search found two existing uses of the term which are not the same, although one of them may be what you have in mind. If you are using an existing term, can you provide a link?

Comment: @DavidGudeman "metaphilosophical pluralism" might be a better fit for what I have in mind. I'll do a search to check for that and edit my post accordingly.

Comment: As SEP describes it, logical pluralism is not "openness to" multiple logics, *that* is perfectly consistent with monism:"Why think that there really are two different correct logics rather than that for the purposes of, say, doing Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis, it’s useful to reason according to an intuitionist logic, rather than classical logic?" Similarly, "methodological pluralism" of SEP, as you call it, is of a superficial sort. We are fallible, so it is prudent to keep our options open, even false views can be useful and worth exploring, charity, etc.

Comment: Substantive philosophical pluralism, analogous to logical pluralism as defined by SEP, would be a rare commodity because, unlike logic, philosophy is all-encompassing. So it would require, at least, perspectivism, if not relativism, about truth (or wisdom), and a global one, not restricted to a particular domain like logic. Arguably, Kekes defends something like that in [Pluralism in Philosophy](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Pluralism_in_Philosophy/jsx4Lvpa1qEC?hl=en) and [Morality of Pluralism](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Morality_of_Pluralism/C1hm6YVlcYoC?hl=en&gbpv=0).

Comment: It's similar to metamath, for instance the grand category of discursive deontic logic with multiple modalities such as obligation, interdiction and unconditional/conditional permission, wherefrom each commands its own base category of real interest possibly inducing its covering counterpart via inclusion or fibration functors potentially satisfying homotopy lifting property so that one can see more and classify and extend things more felicitously. Thus this logical pluralism in terms of typed objects and arrows bears the uni-philosophical *ought implies can* ethics completeness principle...